# Why is this C++ constructor called twice at the same memory location in this implementation of a linked list?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

I was reading Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++ by Shaffer (available for free at https://people.cs.vt.edu/shaffer/Book/) because I saw that it uses templates and I'm trying to learn more about C++ and generic programming in C++.

When the author introduces Linked Lists, he gives a variant that uses a freelist. (This is around pg 111, pdf page 130). In his implementation, he creates a class for a `Link` and overrides `operator new` to pull from the freelist. Then there is a class for `LinkedList`.

However, it turns out that in this implementation, calling `new LinkedList` will cause a constructor to be called by the same object twice, and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

This code shows the relevant parts of the example.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  S()  { std::cout << "ctor at " << this << "\n"; }
  ~S() { std::cout << "dtor at " << this << "\n"; }
};

class Link {
private:
  static Link * freelist;
  S elem;
  Link * next;
public:
  void * operator new(size_t) {
    if (freelist == nullptr) { return ::new Link; }
    Link * tmp = freelist;
    freelist = freelist->next;
    return tmp;
  }
  // other logic
};
Link * Link::freelist = nullptr;

class LinkedList {
private:
  Link * head;
public:
  LinkedList() { head = new Link; }
  // other logic
};

int main() { LinkedList ll; }
```

Example output of this code was

```
ctor at 0x458bbd954eb0
ctor at 0x458bbd954eb0
```

and so we can see that the constructor for the struct `S` was called twice by the same object.

Here is what I would have expected.

1. In `main`, we construct a `LinkedList`.
2. In this LinkedList, we call `new Link`. I believe this invokes `Link::operator new`, which we've overridden.
3. In `Link::operator new`, we see that `Link` sees that its freelist is empty, and so then calls `::new Link`.
4. `::new Link` constructs a Link, including its private member variable `S elem`, constructing an `S` struct.

Clearly this is incorrect. I would bet that I'm missing an implicit `new` from the compiler --- but even then, I'm surprised that a single `S` instance's constructor is called twice. So my mental model is definitely incomplete.

Can you help explain why the constructor is called twice at the same location in memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator new`'s task is to allocate memory; it must *not* call a constructor. The constructor is called automatically after `operator new` returns.

Therefore, your implementation should look like this:

```
void * operator new(size_t size) {
    if (freelist == nullptr) {
       // here is the difference:
       return ::operator new(size);
    }
    Link * tmp = freelist;
    freelist = freelist->next;
    return tmp;
}
```

In your implemenation, the constructor was called from `::new Link`, and then after the pointer was returned, it was called again as usual on the same address.

Of course, you should implement complementary `operator delete`. This one must not call a destructor (that has already been called), but just put the memory into the `freelist`.

Comment: Thank you. Today I learned about the difference between the new expression and new operator. This has been very instructive.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind my asking a short followup, I want to make sure that I understand something. In the original post, when LinkedList is constructed, it calls `new Link`. This is a *new expression*, which will both call `operator new` on Link and then construct it. I'd written a custom `operator new` in Link that calls `::new Link`, which is another *new expression*, and this calls `::operator new` and then constructs Link. Thus there are two *new expressions*, which each construct Link. In your answer, you replaced the inner *new expression* with an *operator new*. Is that right?

Comment: @davidlowryduda Yes, of course, that is the whole point. The `operator new` that we are implementing has to make the space available that can hold a `Link` object. When no space is available on the freelist, we have to take it from somewhere else. The most obvious choice is to use the same allocation function that `::new Link` would use, and that is `::operator new`.